# Why is my heroku worker dyno not working?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord, dyno

I have a worker dyno that I use to run my discord bot. It works normally every day and I have been using it for a long time but suddenly today is just stopped working even though it shows that it turned the dyno on but my bot is still offline and I also have enough hours so it is not a hours problem too(My code is also perfect which I have connected through GitHub pipeline). I cannot figure out what's wrong with the dyno. Does anybody know why it might be happening?

Comment: Are you using free dynos?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was missing the ms module. So I installed the ms module using `npm i ms -s` and then updated my package.json file to Github and when the build was done, it worked.